# Is $C_c^{\infty} (U)$ dense in $L^p(U)$ for $U$ open in $\Bbb{R}^d$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have shown that $C_c^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^d)$ is $L^p$-dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d),$ then I want to show that for arbitrary $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ we also have that $C_c^{\infty} (U)$ is $L^p$ dense in $L^p(U)?$

Is there an easy argument to transfer the density argument from the big space to open subsets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $K$ is a compact subset of $U,$ then there exists $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $0\le f \le 1$ everywhere, $f=1$ on $K,$ with the support of $f$ contained in $U.$

Comment: This is more direct than my idea, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Given $f \in L^p(U)$, replace it with $g \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ by just extending $f$ to be zero outside $U$. Then get a smooth approximation $h$ of $g$. Argue that you can take $h$ to be compactly supported inside $U$. Then $h$ restricted to $U$ is a smooth approximation of $f$.